# Most efficient way to transmit file over TCP

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, stream, base64

I'm currently transmitting files by Gzipping them and then converting to a base64 string, it's working well enough however I'd like to make it more efficient if possible as I'm sure this is not the best way to do it due to the 33% size increase due to Base64.

The two other options I'm considering is directly reading and writing bytes or serializing the object and sending it.

What would be the best way to do this in terms of space? (Im trying to keep the size of the file as small as possible) The files are relatively small around 100kb. I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: Why are you using Base64?

Comment: For 100kb, just call `Write` on the socket.  Otherwise, just look at [`Socket.SendFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No particular reason, it was just the easiest at the time but I've since realized its far from the best solution. As it stands right now Im changing it to just reading and writing from the bytearray but would like to see if there's something better. I haven't used Serialization so Im not sure of what overhead it carries.

Comment: No really, what made you choose to use base64 at all? You say it was "easiest at the time" - but easiest for what purpose? It makes no sense to gzip your file to make it smaller and then base64 the result to make it bigger again. Just send the gzipped data on the socket.

Comment: Easiest in the sense I didn't have to first send the incoming size prior to the file. I was able to convert to a base64 string do Stream.WriteLine(base64string) and string b64 = Stream.ReadLine() on the other end. Convert it back to bytes. Done.

Comment: Sending a size followed by the data is the way to go - and if your data is compressed you can't really do more efficient than that. And IMO it's *much easier* than putting it through base64. Guess what: `Stream.Write(string)` starts by sending the string length :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *don't* want to send length first, you could use this method - after you have acquired the `NetworkStream` object form the connection - for reading *all* data from stream. Again there is no need for base64 in your case, so this solution could read a byte array which it would receive from the sending side via `NetworkStream`.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```